Noise in Bluetooth headphone
I'm using 22.04.4. When I'm connecting my bluetooth headphone there is a constant noise coming. There was no issues in the beginning. I suppose It happened after an update. It's very annoying now. I have tried switching between HFP and A2DP. But it's not working. The headphone is fine.

There seems the issue due to codec compatibility or configuration problems. Can you roll back the update.
